# how to connect to wireless and wifi?

Tags: wireless, connection

I was using my netbook and the system froze,when I try to connect again to the internet via wireless it didnt go thru,try to reboot the system and others and it still dont work  via wireless,also,I cant connect to any free available wifi signals.
Can somebody help me to solve this?

Thanks for any help,Ariel.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely that your netbooks' hardware is failing. I would run a memory test in the least but that sounds like it could be a NIC (Network Interface Card) failing.

Answer (score 0):

- watch for error messages on network card initialization on dbus. 
  Digit in the command line: dmesg
- check the wireless. 
  Digit in the command line: iwconfig
  If the wireless is not started. Digit in the command line:ifconfig wlan0 up
- try manually association.
  e.g. iwconfig wlan0 essid mynet key 16a12bd649ced7ce42ee3f383c